# Merge /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 to /

Tags: linux, debian

I would like to merge `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`.

```
root@server-1:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        40G   13G   25G  35% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  8.5M  1.6G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           782M     0  782M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1        99G   60M   94G   1% /mnt/disk
```

I want to mount them on the `/` The problem that i've datas on `/` (13G), i don't want to lost it.

Thanks

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "merge"? Have the files from both filesystems accessible at each point in a common hierarchy? If so, what if both have the same file name at the same location? It would be best if you could provide an example of expected directory listings from each filesystem and from the "merged" version.

Comment: You cannot mount two different filesystems to one mountpoint and have access to data from both filesystems. What you can do is move some directory to /dev/sdb1, create new mountpoint and mount /dev/sdb1 there. If this is a solution for your task, I could advise in detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i wanted to mount /dev/sdb1 which is situed on /mnt/disk to /. But if i mount /dev/sdb1 on /, i'll lost my /dev/sda1 datas

Comment: You can do this using the logical volume manager (LVM) or by using RAID, but it's a pain in the neck to set up either for a striped volume on an existing system when you can't move the data out of the way, and the failure mode is basically catastrophic (requiring a reinstallation and restore from backup). How much work are you willing to put into this? It is almost certainly a lot easier to just live with the `/` that you have now and move, say, `/home` onto the larger disk. Can we get to see `sudo du -bsm /*/` for a quick overview of how your disk usage is distributed?

Comment: If all you want to do is migrate your root file system to the new disk, then you should probably make it more clear that you're asking about that and not about combining the two disks. That's a lot easier (basically just copy all the files and then a few magic commands to set up the boot loader, followed by switching the boot order so your system boots from the new disk).

Comment: Ok thanks, i wanted to merge sda and sdb to get 140GO (40+100).